# Why does this pattern fail (sometimes) for the continued fraction convergents of $\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, continued-fractions

***Remark: this question is based on a wrong numerical computation and persists only as an example for spurious imprecision in software (see comments)***

This is connected to my [post on the continued fraction convergents of pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508190/). Motivated by Calvin Lin's comment whether a similar pattern exists for other constants, I checked $\sqrt{2}$. Its convergents are,

$$p_n = \frac{1}{1}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{7}{5}, \frac{17}{12}, \frac{41}{29}, \frac{99}{70}, \frac{239}{169},\dots$$

Define the analogous $a,b,c$,

$$a_n,\,b_n,\,c_n = p_{n-2}-1,\;\; p_{n-1}-1,\;\; p_n-1$$

$$v_n=\text{Numerator}\,(a_n)\,\text{Numerator}(b_n)$$

and the same function in the other post,

$$F(n) = \sqrt{\frac{a_n c_n}{a_n-c_n}-v_n}$$

then for even $n>2$, we have,

$$\begin{array}{cc}
n&F(n) \\
4& \sqrt{2} \\ 
6&5\sqrt{2} \\
8&29\sqrt{2} \\
10&169\sqrt{2} \\ 
12&985\sqrt{2} \\
14&5741\sqrt{2}\\
16&33461\sqrt{2} \\ 
\vdots \\
92&\sqrt{\text{huge number}} \\
94&\text{integer}\sqrt{2} \\ 
\vdots \\
\end{array}$$

The sequence $1,5, 29, 169,985,\dots$ is [A001653](http://oeis.org/A001653).

**Question**: *Why does it fail at* $n = 92$ (and other *n* as well) but, when it is $N\sqrt{2}$ again for some integer *N*, then *N* resumes being the correct *kth* term of the OEIS sequence?

**Edit**: As vadim123 pointed out, the case $n=94$ does in fact yield twice a square (and was just a bug in my old Mathematica V 4.)

Comment: What's the huge number?  Is it possible that it's twice a square?

Comment: It's 34041759472536138536782994687493766710446015122061244605489282359202. (And it's square-free.)

Comment: Alas, it is not square-free; in fact it is twice a square: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+34041759472536138536782994687493766710446015122061244605489282359202

Comment: The real mystery is how the hell Wolfram Alpha factors it so quickly.

Comment: No, the mystery is my old Mathematica (Ver. 4) does not show sqrt{34041759472536138536782994687493766710446015122061244605489282359202} as twice a square. Another bug!  :(

Comment: A001653 can be calculated by (((3 + 2*sqrt(2))**n - (3 - 2*sqrt(2))**n) - ((3 + 2*sqrt(2))**(n-1) - (3 - 2*sqrt(2))**(n-1))) / (4*sqrt(2)). Thus, the sqrt(2) is right in it. Line 92 is an error of Mathematica (your version at least).

Comment: @StefanGruenwald: I've been tempted to delete this post, but decided to keep it as an example of a failed experiment. (In this case, using Mathematica Ver 4's Sqrt[] command on very large integers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood of a new sequence agreeing with a known sequence for 45 terms, then never again, is very small.  The likelihood of a sequence agreeing with a known sequence for (apparently) infinitely many terms, but disagreeing for some scattered subset, is almost nil.  This is how I suspected that the disagreement was illusory.

Comment: Thanks. It agreed with the first 45 terms, then sporadically some more within the search radius I used. (Mathematica ver 4's \Sqrt[n] function leaves much to be desired.)