# Gauss-Kuzmin distribution proof

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, probability-distributions, analytic-number-theory

Apologies if this has already been asked here, but I wasn’t able to find it. The [Gauss-Kuzmin distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kuzmin_distribution) is the [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_theory_(statistics)) [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) of the coefficients of the [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of [almost all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number):

$$p(k)=-\log_{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{(1+k)^{2}}\right)$$

All proofs of this result and similar results that I have encountered use [ergodic theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory) (e.g. [here](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2014/984650/) and [here](http://www.geometrie.tugraz.at/karpenkov/cf2011/cf2011s_7.pdf) and [here](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783642393679)) which I am not very familiar with. I would really like to get some understanding of this formula though, since I believe that from it one can derive formulae like [Khinchin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin%27s_constant) (e.g. according to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1360459/284973)). I was wondering if anyone knew of and could provide a proof of this result that does not use ergodic theory, perhaps even just more basic real or complex analysis and number theory?

Comment: You can find the proof without ergodic theory in Khinchins book-Continued Fractions. Kuzmin's original proof doesn't use ergodic theory explicitly.